# Parsing issue with redis,logstash and elastic search

Tags: redis

I setup two node on aws  and my architecture is below
Logstash shipper host A
Redis-logstash-elastic search host B

We tried to parse the log with shipper it works fine for the first log file.
Again I tried to parse the second file the connection was made properly.But the file parsing is not started.

My question is is  needs to delete any cache for redis or any file like .sincedb .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to delete all the .sincedb file if you want to reparse.

Please refer to [here](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/inputs/file#sincedb_path). Beside that, if you want to parse the file from the beginning, also make sure you have set the [start_position](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/inputs/file#start_position) to `beginning`.

Comment: Thank you so much.I included the start_position on indexer conf file it's work like charm :)